# $\langle f(x),x \rangle =0$ for every $x\in V$ if and only if $f^*=-f$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $V$ be a real vector space with inner product and $f:V\rightarrow V$, show that
> $\langle f(x),x \rangle =0$ for every $x\in V$ if and only if $f^*=-f$, what are the eigenvalues?

---

**my solution:** $\langle f(x),x \rangle =0 (1) \Leftrightarrow \langle x,f^*(x) \rangle =0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{\langle x,f^*(x) \rangle }=0 \Leftrightarrow \langle f^*(x),x \rangle =0 (2)$

$(1)+(2)= \langle f(x)+f^*(x),x \rangle =0$ since this is true for every $x$ from the properties of the inner product it must be $f(x)+f^*(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow  f^*=-f$

for the eigenvalues: let $f(x)=λx$,  $\underset{=\langle λx,x \rangle }{\langle f(x),x \rangle }=\underset{\langle -λx,x \rangle }{\langle -f^*(x),x \rangle }$

Meaning $-λ=λ$ so the eigenvalues are all zero ?

Comment: Is $T$ the same as $f$?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The latte are operators, so they leave space on both sides; the former are delimeters, so the spacing is correct for them.

Comment: i made a mistake yes $T=f$

Comment: When you conclude that $f+f^*=0$ that is not properly justified.

Comment: But it's true for every $x$ the only element that does that is $0$, i believe its proven as property

Comment: If that were true you can apply it to $\langle fx,x\rangle$ and conclude that $f=0$. You might be remembering a similar property with $\langle fx,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: isn't the same since there is no $y$ ?

Comment: You need to prove that $\langle fx,y\rangle=\langle x,-fy\rangle$ for all $x,y$. You can use the analogous of [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Real_vector_spaces) expressing $\langle fx,y\rangle$ in terms of $\langle f(x+y),(x+y)\rangle$, $\langle fx,x\rangle$ and $\langle fy,y\rangle$.

Comment: So this isn't  correct, thanks for answering

Comment: Just compute $0=\langle f(x+y),(x+y)\rangle=\langle fx,x\rangle+\langle fy,y\rangle+\langle fx,y\rangle+\langle x,fy\rangle=\langle fx,y\rangle+\langle x,fy\rangle$. Therefore, for all $x,y$ we have $\langle fx,y\rangle=\langle x,-fy\rangle$.

Comment: $\langle x,y \rangle =\langle y,x \rangle$ this is true always ?

Comment: @PetrosK, Yes this is true for any inner product on a real vector space because an inner product is a symmetric form.